# Equation Creation for Magic Square style logic

Tags: javascript, math, dynamic-arrays, magic-square

I am trying to bring logic and programming to a currently manually driven process.

We take the weights of 16 different crushing hammers, organize them into sets of 4 based on how close each set's weight is to the others.  We are looking to have less than 1 pound difference between all 4 sets.  The weights are known but I cannot logically program a method to do this without pen and paper.

Example below.

|  | Set A | Set B | Set C | Set D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 39.1 | 40.1 | 42.0 | 41.5 |
|  | 40.05 | 41.0 | 40.05 | 38.90 |
|  | 41.2 | 42.1 | 41.3 | 43.1 |
|  | 38.5 | 43.60 | 42.1 | 41.5 |
| Totals | 158.85 | 166.80 | 165.45 | 165 |

As you can see in the first example, Sets C and D are close enough.  Sets A and B are too far apart and need readjusting, but due to the severe difference, I would most likely have to rearrange all 4 sets to get with 1 pound difference for all 4 sets.  Now mind you, this is all done on paper, and I am looking for a way to plug in all numbers and have it spit out the best configuration given the hammer weights, no more paper.

|  | Set A | Set B | Set C | Set D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 42.1 | 39.1 | 42.0 | 41.5 |
|  | 40.05 | 41.0 | 40.05 | 38.90 |
|  | 43.60 | 43.1 | 41.3 | 42.1 |
|  | 38.5 | 41.20 | 40.1 | 41.5 |
| Totals | 164.25 | 164.40 | 163.45 | 164 |

I could do this all day, splitting hairs to get as close as possible.  The closer we get the weights, the less vibration we experience and our equipments last a lot longer.  Anyone have any thoughts to accomplishing this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a good math guy but I think in order to arrange ALL 4 SETS within 1lb tolerance, all 16 hammers should have some what consistent weight that is a bit apart from targeted weight.

The most simple way I can think of is to sort all of them in order and assign index 0~3 to each group until all 16 are assigned.

Comment: I appreciate the input, but I would need a program that would essentially try ever iteration or combination of hammers to find the best arrangement.  And I believe at 16 hammers, there is like 2 million combos.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).